# How to change input border-color

Tags: html, css

[input](http://jsfiddle.net/bhGjn)

When I click on the input to create a blue border.

what i do to make not this border?

```
input{border:0px; border-bottom:1px solid black;}
</head>
<body>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this:

```
input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```